# move the selection Column to right side in a UI-Grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm using ui-grid, and I want to move the selection column to the right side.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ability is apparently [not yet supported](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/4862). It's a possible enhancement that's under consideration, though, depending on users' demand for it, so you may as well indicate your interest.

Comment: Thank you. I will check for a solution

Comment: @Bennett Adams Do we have that option to move selection to right  side now?

Comment: @Coder002 Where u able to achieve this?